# Laravel 5 global model methods?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a number of tables / models setup that have 'locked_at' and 'locked_by' columns, in essence what I would like to do is call something like:

```
$model->lock();
```

This method would check that row is not already locked, set the both cells and then save the model.

I can create the lock method inside each of my models, but that doesn't seem like the best idea. I would prefer to create the method once and have it accessible to all models.

Is there a way of doing this in laravel?

Comment: Consider a trait, like Laravel uses for soft deletion. https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/SoftDeletingTrait.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like ceejayoz suggested, you could achieve it by using a Trait.

**Step 1**

Create a folder called Traits and inside that create trait class like the following

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

trait Lockable {

    public function lock() {
        $this->lock = 1;
        $this->save();
    }
}
```

**Step 2:**

Now import the trait on your model class like the following

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use App\Traits\Lockable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Lockable;
}
```

Thats it! Now you could call the function like

```
$user = \App\User::find(1);
$user->lock();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create `BaseModel` class that extends `Model` and make all your models that using `lock()` method extend `BaseModel` class instead of the`Model`. Then just define `lock()` method in the `BaseModel` class.

Comment: Better to use a trait, IMO.